# Crosssell Products on Product Pages displaying disabled products - Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, cross-sells

I have a code snippet to display cross-sell products on the product page via `catalog/product/view.phtml`.

It displays the product's cross-sell items, however it also displays disabled products.

Can anyone advise how I can filter only enabled products with the code below?

```
<?php if($_crossSellProducts = $_product->getCrossSellProducts()): ?>

    <div class="topproducts_containter">
    <div class="topsellerTitle">TOP <?php echo strtoupper(Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getName()); ?> PRODUCTS</div>

    <?php foreach ($_crossSellProducts as $_item): ?>
        <?php $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>

        <div class="col-sx-12 col-sm-2 items">
            <div class="img">
                <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(100, 150); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>">
                        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                       <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
            </div>
       </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add condition that if product enabled then it shows on product details page. Try below code where we have to add `if($_item->getStatus() == 1)` condition:-

```
<?php if($_crossSellProducts = $_product->getCrossSellProducts()): ?>

    <div class="topproducts_containter">
    <div class="topsellerTitle">TOP <?php echo strtoupper(Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getName()); ?> PRODUCTS</div>

    <?php foreach ($_crossSellProducts as $_item): ?>
        <?php $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>

    <?php if($_item->getStatus() == 1):?>
        <div class="col-sx-12 col-sm-2 items">
            <div class="img">
                <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(100, 150); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>">
                        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
                       <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
            </div>
       </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That did indeed do the trick. Thanks @raj